# How do I get parent_box to fit property without overflowing?

Tags: html, css

In the code below I would like `#parent_box` to fit into the body. When items are added to `#left_child` the height of `#parent_box` grows.

how do I stop that?

Setting `overflow-y: auto` to `#left_child` doesn't seem to help.

```js
let box = document.getElementById('left_box')
for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
  let e = document.createElement('div')
  e.innerText = 'some text goes here'
  box.appendChild(e)
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 50vh;
}

#outer_box {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#parent_box {
  display: flex;
  max-height: inherit;
}

#left_box,
#right_box {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: inherit;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#left_box {
  background: grey;
}

#left_box div {
  flex: 1;
}

#right_box {
  background: yellow;
}

#line {
  min-height: 20px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer_box">
  <div>item1</div>
  <div>item2</div>
  <div id="parent_box">
    <div id="left_box"></div>
    <div id="right_box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="line"></div>
```

`#parent_box` to fit the remaining space in the body.

Comment: Sidenote: The `<style>` tag has to be placed within the `<head>` element. Placing it within the body is only valid with the usage of the `scope` attribute which was deprecated around 2016. As such it is not longer valid to do so.

Comment: I have found a solution. The trick is to add `max-height: inherit` to #outer_box. Plus `overflow: hidden` to #parent_box.

Comment: You can self-answer your question with an answer instead of commenting on it!

Answer (score 0):

As stated in my comment above.
Add `max-height: inherit` to `#outer_box`, `overflow: hidden` to `#parent_box`

```
#outer_box {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: inherit
}

#parent_box {
  display: flex;
  max-height: inherit;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```